# Installing IPython 0.12 on Windows 7 64

Tags: python, windows-7, 64-bit, ipython

I read the installation notes [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/install/install.html#windows). The installation notes say that for Windows 7 64 I should probably follow this  method:

> Install from source, but using setuptools (python setupegg.py
>   install).

So I first installed Python 2.7.2 using the official binaries: `python-2.7.2.amd64.msi` and later downloaded `ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg` which I understand has the source for IPython.

However, I could not find any file called `setupegg.py` after decompressing `ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg`. Is this file part of the `.egg` file I downloaded or should I get it from somewhere else?

Also, is there anything else I need to install in order to use the new IPython notebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you try methods 1 (`easy_install ipython`) or 2 (the exe installer) first. Note that in any case, you should install [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions) first. (If you really want to use method 3, you'll need to get the source zip, not the egg.)

To run the notebook, you also need pyzmq and tornado. Both are on PyPI, or Christoph Gohlke has [Windows installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) of these and many other packages.

As a shortcut to all of this, you can use a Python distribution like [EPD Free](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php).

Comment: After installing EPD Free.. then how do you open a notebook in the browser? What python commands?

Comment: If you go to a system command prompt, it should be `ipython notebook`. There might be a start menu shortcut for it - I don't use EPD myself, so I don't know.

Comment: When doing that it says: Could not open file <notebook> for safe execution. -and then it opens a standard ipython console

Comment: When it starts, what version of IPython does it say you have? The notebook is in 0.12 and above.

Comment: I have updated to version 0.13 and it is working now.. >D thank you for your time